# Keep the conditional formatting on pasting value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For a particular column I have conditional formatting to fill cell colour when there is value change.

When pasting a value from different column, conditional formatting is removed.

How do I keep the conditional formatting?

Comment: Use 'Paste Values and number format' ?

Comment: hi ...i think this maybe helpful https://superuser.com/questions/649675/preserve-conditional-formatting-on-cut-paste

Comment: Is there any way to keep the formatting instead Every time pressing macro shortcut.

Comment: @GK_ yes just don't overwrite the formatting and just past values and number format. That will keep the original formatting of the cell you paste into.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent that the conditional formatting is overwritten (and therefore deleted on the destination cell). Workaround is that you immediately reassign the formatting. You can use the `Worksheet.Change`-event that is fired when the value of a cell is changed.

The following code is an example, try if it helps you. Put the code into the Worksheet-Module of the sheet and adapt it to the range (column) with the formatting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim formattedRange As Range
    Set formattedRange = Range("E:E")
    If Intersect(Target, formattedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim fc As FormatCondition, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To formattedRange.FormatConditions.Count
        Set fc = formattedRange.FormatConditions(i)
        fc.ModifyAppliesToRange formattedRange
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**

When the pasted cells have already conditional formatting, this formatting will get copied to the destination and the code will apply it to the whole `formattedRange`. I updated the routine, the following logic deletes all formatting that was introduced by the modified cells. Note that you need to run the loop backwards because of the deletion.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim formattedRange As Range
    Set formattedRange = Range("E:E")
    If Intersect(Target, formattedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim fc As FormatCondition, i As Integer
    For i = formattedRange.FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set fc = formattedRange.FormatConditions(i)
        If fc.AppliesTo.Address <> formattedRange.Address _
           And Not Intersect(Target, fc.AppliesTo) Is Nothing Then
            fc.Delete
        Else
            fc.ModifyAppliesToRange formattedRange
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working for me. Could you explain, how it will apply my existing formatting to the destination cell.

Comment: Have you adapted the code (change `formattedRange` to the column or range of your choice)? Code loops over all cond. formatting in that range and will apply it to the whole range again.

Comment: actually my existing conditional format is little complicated, i check multiple items to change the cell colour..........................

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("financial").Range(Target.Address)
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
Formula1:="=IF(OR($AV$9="No",AND($AV$9="Yes")),IF($Y$9=$AJ$9,FALSE,TRUE),FALSE)"
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
End With

Comment: But when i enter the above formula in VBA code, it is showing error

Comment: Don't understand why you want to rewrite the whole condition. Entering formulas with VBA is usually a little tricky. What I see is that you have to double all quotes within the formula (eg `""Yes""'`) so that VBA doesn't think that it reaches the end of the string

Comment: Assume i have Rule defined to change colour in conditional formatting for a column(D). When the condition satifies it change colour. But if i copy value from another columns then the rule condition is overwriting there, so colour is not changing. 
So as you mentioned above i wrote "Worksheet_Change" method so here i thought to rewrite my condtion

Comment: ...and I showed the code not to rewrite the condition(s) but to apply the condition(s) again to the whole range. You just need to adapt the range address to your need (I used the whole column "E" as example). Your attempt will work only if a) the formula is applied correctly (which is tricky and error prone) and b) you never decide to change the conditional formatting rules

Comment: I tried the code and changed range accordingly. It didn't work for me

Comment: And what means "If didn't work"? Have you tried to figure out?

Comment: i tried but i dont understand what it is doing(i.m new to VBA). so i tried to apply the exact formula for the target cell

Comment: But you have of course used the debugger to understand? My code is rather simple, it just loops over all conditional formatting of a certain range and resets the appliesTo-range. Check: Is the subroutine executed at all (if not, the name is wrong), is the loop entered (if not, the range is wrongly defined) or is the appliesTo-Range not set (no idea why this could happen)

Comment: Your code resets everything. Example, previously for one cell some condition applied means, it resets that also

Comment: Every time i copy paste values to the cells, Conditional formatting count for the column is getting double.

Comment: Do you copy some cells that come from a range that also has conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes correct the copied cells contains some formatting.. is it possible to remove it ?